# What does mavenAuthenticateFeed do in the Azure DevOps MavenTask?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

From the MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops

> **mavenFeedAuthenticate** **Authenticate built-in Maven feeds**   (Required)
> Automatically authenticate Maven feeds from Azure Artifacts. If
> built-in Maven feeds are not in use, deselect this option for faster
> builds. Default value: false Argument aliases: mavenAuthenticateFeed

But everytime I want to use a Maven feeds from Azure Artifacts and I try this by setting mavenFeedAuthenticate to true I always get 401 (Unauthorized).

Could someone please show me the correct usage of this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops) to check if you have given **Contributor/Owner** role to identities: **Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})** and **{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})** as this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities) described.

In addition, this `mavenFeedAuthenticate` argument in the [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) is set to **false** *by default*, which means that Azure Pipelines will automatically authenticate Maven feeds from Azure Artifacts in the backend. But if it is set to true, we need to specify [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) with full scopes in settings.xml and add file path pointing to this settings.xml for authentication in *Options* menu in this [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks Edward, I'm sure I've done that and it still fails with Unauthorized when setting to true, but when setting it to false it works, so I'm confused really what the mavenAuthenticateFeed actually does.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in my side. But refer to this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/365121/maven-task-wont-authenticate-in-azure-artifacts.html, please use the task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops. You could set variable system.debug to true to get debug logs to troubleshoot this issue. Also long version string of package might cause this issue like https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/387890/authenticate-maven-with-artifact-feed.html mentioned.

Comment: Hi Edward, yeah if I use the MavenAuthenticate and set the mavenAuthenticateFeed to false, it can authenticate against the feed okay. if I dont use MavenAuthenticate, set the mavenAuthenticateFeed to false, and include my own settings.xml with feed (with the username as AzureDevOps) it works... but again the mavenAuthenticateFeed has to be false. It's a strange one...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please firstly check the feed permissions by following doc: [Package permissions in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines).

Comment: Thanks Edwards, in all the use cases I've tested with mavenFeedAuthenticate when setting to true even with a PAT fails. But I'm going to accept your answer :)